# Обобщённое приведение IQueryable к IOrderedQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

У меня есть generic метод преобразующий `IQueryable<T>` и возвращающий `IOrderedQuerable<T>` при помощи Linq-to-Entities.

Простой способ `input.OrderBy(p => p.something)` не работает, так как я не знаю свойства `T` и проставить какое-либо ограничение.

Каст результата к `IOrderedQuerable<T>` якобы работает, пока в рантайме не вызывать методы типа `.Skip()` или `.Take()`, что вызовет ошибку.

Думаю, что теоретически можно использовать рефлексию, но это кажется достаточно грязным хаком.

Как можно решить подобную задачу?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Casting IQueryable to IOrderedQueryable generically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14524427/5752652) от участника  [@Toodleey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934487/toodleey).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14524427

Answer (score 1):

Используйте:

```
input.OrderBy(p => 0);
```

При этом никакая сортировка применяться не будет. Однако это потребует некоторых накладных расходов процессора.

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Casting IQueryable to IOrderedQueryable generically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14524571/5752652)  от участника  [@RePierre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/844006/repierre).</sub>